# What's the easiest way to remove the license plate on the Time Machine?

Tags: disassembly, window

I have the 10300 Back to the Future Time Machine. I'm assembling it for the first time, [Following the directions](https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/6413319.pdf). and I'm at the end where they're allowing me to pick which of the three I want to install. I started down for the first movie, and it's asking me to put in the license plate, into the frame. (The license plate is piece number [60602](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60602&idColor=12#T=C&C=12). The frame is item number [60593](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60593&idColor=11#T=C&C=11).)

[image: p245 step 414]

I'm a little hesitant to put it in, because I'm not sure how I could remove it. The license plate frame snapped in.

[image: p236 step 402]

So now there isn't a good way to remove the license plate holder.

What are my options for removing the license plate? I only can think of one: Just start removing pieces from the bumper until I can access the back of the license plate frame, to push the frame out, or plate itself.

Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I would approach it, is to start by lifting off the two big black "exhausts" (with the cooling fins) at the back of the vehicle. These were installed in steps 292 and 302 resp. :

[image]

That should give you access to the back of the license plate holder. Via the gaps on either side of the blue sloped bricks, you should be able to push out the license plate holder from the back (a finger might not fit, so a thinner tool might be needed). An earlier construction state shows the gap more clearly from a different angle :

[image]

You can just about see one of the two balls which the license plate holder sockets slot onto.

To make access easier, you can additionally lift off the plate installed in step 203 :

[image]

Once the license plate holder is out, you can simply push the license plate out from the back (again with a thin tool - like eg. a brick separator).

This [video by 2bricks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBfP54U8jQA) demonstrates this procedure, but with a twist. They've adapted the license plate holder slightly to make removal much more convenient. If you intend to swap license plates regularly, that might be an option for you.

Comment: This is very helpful. I like the video recommendation. I might see if I can find a spare one of those pieces lying around. You also said "so a thinner tool might be needed". Care to elaborate on a good tool?

Comment: @McKay a plastic [spudger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spudger) (multi-packs for a couple of $/€/£ on ebay) is good when a brick separator won't fit, and generally handy for tinkering with gadgets.

Comment: Or an [axle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3737) in a pinch.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker an axle won't fit in the hole.

Comment: While I don't have any spudgers, the space was narrow, but I was able to have success with a sim ejector tool